# Oracle - using case with nested query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ora-00907

I have syntax for oracle like this :

```
select 'Tanggal : '||to_char(c,'DD-MON-YYYY hh:mm:ss')||',' as Tgl,
case
    when (select ((a.sk/b.tot)*100)
          from (select count(to_char(response))sk
          from log where response like '%OK%')a,
         (select count(*)tot from log)b)<100
    then (select 'Error : '||to_char(response),count(to_char(response)) je
        from log
        group by to_char(response)
        order by je desc)
    else 
        (select 'Success Rate : '||substr((a.sukses/b.total)*100,1,5)||' %,'as Success_rate
            from (select count(to_char(response)) sukses from log where response like '%OK%')a, (select count(*) total from log)b)
    end as test
from log
where rownum <= 1;
```

But it send error message `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis,` 
it refers to "order by je desc". 
 So, what should i do that there are no error ?

Comment: You forgot to tag other **RDBMS** like `sql server`, `db2`, `postgresql`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/tour Always **format your code** while posting. Pay attention while using **tags**. And please post a test case. Just asking **"why is this code not working"** is considered an off-topic question. Show the tables involved, with some sample data.

Comment: You cannot use an order by like this. I guess you want to retrieve the first value, so in that case you should use first agregation function. If you retrieve 2 lines, your query will fail. If you retrieve only one line you dont need the order by.

Comment: In your case, at the "when" level, you have something like "when a, b < 100" - I thing your error probably comes from this part. you should probable add a greatest function if you want to reproduce the OR function or simply use a OR.

Comment: @APC you can perfectly use subquerries in case... select 
case
    when (    (select 1 from dual) a
            )<100
    then (select 1 
        from dual)
    else 
        (select 2 from dual)
    end as test
from dual
where rownum <= 1;

Answer (score 0):

You query is really ugly, there is tons of thing to do to improve that, but just looking at the strange things in your code, there are 2 wrong syntax

```
select ((a.sk/b.tot)*100)
from (select count(to_char(response))sk
from log where response like '%OK%')a,
(select count(*)tot from log)b)<100
```

The part where you have
`)a,
(select` .... it is not possible to have this.
It's like (a,b)<100 which has no meaning

Then the `order by` is also wrong. Just remove it. And try again